# How to get added file with SVNKit

Tags: java, svnkit

I have a Working Copy and added new files FOUR.txt and more/FIVE.txt using `svn add` command.

```
svn add FOUR.txt
svn add more/FIVE.txt
```

On executing svn status on working copy I get following output

```
A FOUR.txt
A more/FIVE.txt
```

Now I want to get same info with SVNKit API. So, I written code like this

```
SVNClientManager.newInstance().getStatusClient().doStatus(tempRepoWorkingCopy, SVNRevision.WORKING, SVNDepth.INFINITY, false, true, true, true, new ISVNStatusHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleStatus(SVNStatus status) throws SVNException {
                System.out.println(status.getContentsStatus());
                System.out.println(status.getFile());                   
            }

        }, null);
```

It is giving `getContentStatus()` as Modified instead of Added. How to get Added information using `SVNStatusClient`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SVNStatus.getNodeStatus()` does the job!

Comment: Actually, the correct answer is SVNStatus.getCombinedNodeAndContentsStatus(), this method is used to implement status printing in SVNKit command line client.